How do I make PowerShell register interactive prompts as output when being ran as a subprocess?
I need to be able to capture the prompts of interactive commands and redirect them to the user of my reverse shell.
I have tried using various PTY crates. However, most are oriented to unix systems. And, the few windows oriented crates there are, are usually very poorly documented and I am not able to understand their usage at all.
Keep in mind please. I am not at all familiar with the windows API, and I have very little idea of how things work on the back end. So please, be as verbose as possible when writing out answers. That said, any help is appreciated regardless.
